# Why was Cussley only depicted from behind?

Tags: godzilla, shin-godzilla

In the Funimation English dub version of "Shin Godzilla", there is an odd scene in a plane where "Kayoko Patterson" character is speaking with a "US Official" who is only identified by the text floating over him as "Cussley".  They are together in a airplane.  She gets off after, but we never see his face.

The shots are only of the back of his head and his hands, reminiscent of the cuts in English adaptation of Godzilla, "Godzilla: King of the Monsters", where actors are only shot from the back so it can look like the American narrator / expositor is speaking with other people from the original film's Japanese cast without needing them to shoot actual scenes with him.

I could think of several reasons for this being done here, for instance cost savings, lack of an available actor so a Japanese actor was filmed with his back to the camera, etc.

I assume both the characters are speaking English. Since I rented the dubbed VOD, and I never see the face of "Cussley", I have no idea if it's his original voice or a dub in the Japanese version.  "Kayoko" is over-dubbed the whole time by Funimation's actress, but that doesn't tell me if her Japanese actress was speaking English or not in that scene.  Reading her lips is tough, but I assume she was.

Mostly I'm just curious if this was an intentional reference.  But for all I know, "Cussley" is an actor who had to be cut from the original for some contractual reason?  Maybe a combination of many things.

Such an amusing mirror of the insertions from the American re-cutting of the first film, I mostly wonder if the creators were even aware of that as they were shooting.  They certainly cast many other English speaking American accented actors in the film elsewhere.

It's a very odd scene, anyway.  Any ideas on why this was shot this way?

Comment: It has been a while since I watched it, but I'm sure Kayoko spoke English in the original version, since her character is an American with a Japanese heritage.

Comment: I have the Japanese version and he (and the actress) both are speaking English and we don't see his face in that either. In fact, most if not all of the Caucasian actors in movie speak in English (or in once case German) rather than Japanese....unless it was appropriate.